# Cannot fetch Signed_request from facebook in request, Pass params to Page Tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, express

I'm using an express backend and have an app which will need to be customized the url of the page tab with unique id's for every fan page on facebook. (Using `app_data`)

Problem is I cannot seem to get the `signed_request` parameter, in the POST request made by FB.

I've even tried using a library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb-signed-parser but the param can't be found and it fails.

`app.post('*', function(req, res){
  console.log(req);
  //var signed_request = req.param('signed_request');
....`

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: So what’s the result of the console.log statement?

Comment: Fixed it myself CBroe, I needed to parse the POST params to get the signed_request. The raw req object did not have that param.